# Insert into RockMongo JSON collection exported with mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have problem with export data from my local database to my hosting. I exported data with this command:

```
 mongoexport --db fol -c like --out exportfol.like.json
```

and got json file which looks like this:

```
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "550acb815fa67ddc1aa67633" }, "to" : 263449651, "from" : 264717017, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-19T16:13:37.070+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "550c20d08eecd30c15e4a207" }, "from" : 12680198, "to" : 1385847, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-20T16:29:52.004+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "550c313e8eecd30c15e4a208" }, "to" : 35545833, "from" : 12680198, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-20T17:39:58.218+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5512aa5ec1baea98151dd403" }, "from" : 12680198, "to" : 13666889, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-25T15:30:22.967+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
```

Problem starts when I trying to import this data in rockmongo. When I import into collection from json file I am getting exeption

```
exception: field names cannot start with $ [$oid] at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:159
```

Is there any way to port data to rockmongo?

Comment: You should insert the data using mongoimport, not by trying to import it to RockMongo. Better yet, if you're moving data from one MongoDB to another, use mongodump and mongorestore.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the file leaving it well:

```
{"_id" : 550acb815fa67ddc1aa67633", "to" : 263449651, "from" : 264717017, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-19T16:13:37.070+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
{"_id" : 550c20d08eecd30c15e4a207", "from" : 12680198, "to" : 1385847, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-20T16:29:52.004+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
{"_id" : 550c313e8eecd30c15e4a208", "to" : 35545833, "from" : 12680198, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-20T17:39:58.218+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
{"_id" : 5512aa5ec1baea98151dd403", "from" : 12680198, "to" : 13666889, "fromDate" : { "$date" : "2015-03-25T15:30:22.967+0300" }, "mutual" : false }
```

and then try again

Comment: Problem was solved long time ago with mongodump, mongorestore and SSH access to host server. But anyway thanks for advise!

Comment: I found that this left the IDs not really being IDs... instead I changed `{ "$oid" : "550acb815fa67ddc1aa67633" }` to `ObjectId("550acb815fa67ddc1aa67633")`. Even though it's not valid JSON, rockmongo accepted it and made them real IDs.